# How to declare a method which may return 3 different kinds of type?

Tags: scala, types

I want to define a method, but it's return type has 3 kinds.

```
def findSelectedItem: ??? = { ... }
```

The `???` here may be `Category`, `Section`, `Page`, but I'm not sure how to find a proper type to represent it.

If it's just 2, I can use `Either[Type1, Type2]`, but it's 3 now.

Do I need to declare something like `Either` but which has 3 type variables? Or is there already something I can just use?

Comment: Can you define a common trait?

Comment: Scalaz has an Either3 class that should suit your needs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could nest `Either`:

Given

```
case class Category(name: String)
case class Section(name: String)
case class Page(name: String)
```

and a method like this:

```
def f(name: String): Either[Category, Either[Section, Page]] = {
  name match {
    case "c" =>
      Left(Category(name))

    case "s" =>
      Right(Left(Section(name)))

    case "p" =>
      Right(Right(Page(name)))
  }
}
```

then you can "pattern match" on the result:

```
Seq("c", "s", "p").map(f).foreach {
  case Left(c) => println("C")
  case Right(Left(s)) => println("S")
  case Right(Right(p)) => println("p")
}
```

---

As an alternative, create your own `Either3`:

```
case class Either3[+A, +B, +C](left: Option[A], middle: Option[B], 
                               right: Option[C])

object Left3 {
  def apply[A, B, C](a: A): Either3[A, B, C] = {
    Either3(Some(a), None, None)
  }

  def unapply[A, B, C](e: Either3[A, B, C]): Option[A] = {
    e.left
  }
}

object Middle3 {
  def apply[A, B, C](b: B): Either3[A, B, C] = {
    Either3(None, Some(b), None)
  }

  def unapply[A, B, C](e: Either3[A, B, C]): Option[B] = {
    e.middle
  }
}

object Right3 {
  def apply[A, B, C](c: C): Either3[A, B, C] = {
    Either3(None, None, Some(c))
  }

  def unapply[A, B, C](e: Either3[A, B, C]): Option[C] = {
    e.right
  }
}
```

and then

```
def f(name: String): Either3[Category, Section, Page] = {
  name match {
    case "c" =>
      Left3(Category(name))

    case "s" =>
      Middle3(Section(name))

    case "p" =>
      Right3(Page(name))
  }
}
```

together with

```
Seq("c", "s", "p").map(f).foreach {
  case Left3(c) => println("C")
  case Middle3(s) => println("S")
  case Right3(p) => println("p")
}
```

Comment: +1.  @Freewind, the Either3 solution is more powerful because it allows you return one of *any* 3 types without having to make them share a common supertype.  If the 3 types are only related in that they may be returned by this function, yoking them together as case classes would deform your type/class hierarchy.